# Value of Final Velocity of Dropped Object

Tags: kinematics, velocity

When an object such as a feather is dropped from a height, the initial velocity is said to be $0$. I would assume that the final velocity would also be $0$ as when the feather reaches the ground, it stops moving. However, the final velocity is not $0$. Could anyone please answer why?

Comment: Who claims that the final velocity is not 0 and are you sure they don't mean the velocity right *before* the ground stops the object?

Comment: If you use the third equation of motion, namely $v^2 = \ u^2 +\ 2as$, will you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the ground is at $x=1$ cm, imagine to move it below, at $x=0$ cm. What would be the velocity at $x=1$ cm? It is non zero.

You can think of the final velocity as the velocity the object has just before it hits the ground.

Answer (score 0):

The feather has mass, and therefore if you will drop it from a certain height, it will accelerate (F = mg) and will surely gain velocity. ( Though, its velocity will become constant after some time when it attains terminal velocity, but it will not be equal to zero.